# I am getting this warning as my react app starts

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of `<Component />` from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
>   in span
>   in a
>   in li
>   in ul
>   in div
>   in div
>   in div
>   in Header
>   in div
>   in div
>   in t
>   in master
>   in Connect(master)
>   in Switch
>   in Router
>   in Provider

```html
const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(generalActionLoad());


ReactDOM.render(

 <Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={history}>
   {routes}
  </Router>
 </Provider>
 , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

My routes.js :

```html
export default (

  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/abcd" component={Locked} />

    {/* <Route onEnter={requireAuth}> */}
    <Master  >
      
      < Switch >
        <Route exact path="/abcdefg"  component={abcdefg}/> 
      </ Switch>
     
    </Master>
    {/* </Route>;  */}

    <Route exact path="*" components={NotFound} />
  </Switch>

);
```

Comment: First of all, change abcdefg to Abcdefg. Then, can you post abcdefg? Also, what happens when you go to xxx/abcd in the browser? what happens when you go to xxx/abcd? (xxx is the http path that is opened when you run the app)

Answer (score 1):

Your Routes.js is an expression, not a function since you are just exporting JSX.

Behind the scenes, jsx is really just javascript functions. So when you write

```
<Switch>
 <Route> ...
```

It looks like this when compiled:

```
React.createElement(Switch, {},
  React.createElement(Route, {}, ...
```

This should work if you wrap your jsx in a function.

```
export default () => (

  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/abcd" component={Locked} />

    {/* <Route onEnter={requireAuth}> */}
    <Master  >

      < Switch >
        <Route exact path="/abcdefg"  component={abcdefg}/> 
      </ Switch>

    </Master>
    {/* </Route>;  */}

    <Route exact path="*" components={NotFound} />
  </Switch>

);
```

Also Components need to be uppercased. I don't know what your abcdefg component is, if it was just there as an example or an actual component, but you'll need to rename it to something that starts with a Capital letter so react knows its a component.

Comment: I worked on your suggestions but in vain , new errors             
 checkPropTypes.js:19 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Router`, expected a ReactNode.
    in Router

 Uncaught Error: A <Router> may have only one child element

Comment: I missed this before, but why do you have this <Master> tag? If you want a nested route, put it inside of the route, not inside of the <Switch >. So  in your example... inside of abcdefg put a Switch in your render function with any nested routes.

Check up the documentation of react route, A Switch renders a the first Route with a matching path. If you exclude the Switch, any routes that match your path will get displayed.

Comment: in this code i have shown just only one route , but i have to include many nested routes that's why i have used switch